# What is the microstructural explanation for the high Poisson's ratio of rubber?

Tags: material-science, elasticity

Natural rubber has the highest quoted Poisson's ratio I've seen for a real material, usually given as 0.4999. This obviously makes intuitive sense when you think about the behaviour of rubber, and I've seen it explained several times as being a result of the high ratio between bulk modulus and shear modulus of rubber, but I'm interested to know if there's a microstructural explanation for it. Does it have to do with a polymeric composition? Is there anything I can go read that gets into this in detail?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Our starting point: *"...with compact, weakly compressible materials such as liquids and
rubbers, where stress primarily results in shape change, ν →  ½*" (Greaves et al, "[Poisson’s ratio and modern materials](http://fulltext.calis.edu.cn/nature/nmat/10/11/nmat3134.pdf)").

Why does this occur with rubbers (perhaps more precisely called [elastomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomer) in this context)?

As Hertzberg notes in *Deformation and Fracture Mechanics of Engineering Materials*,

*"A polymer molecule is constructed with covalent bonds along its length, but links
between polymer chains may be strong covalent bonds (cross-links), weak secondary bonds, or
a mixture of the two. Polymers without cross-links are called thermoplastics because they have
the ability to melt and remelt. Polymers with many cross-links cannot melt after they have been
solidified, and so are called thermosets."*

*"At low temperatures
the modulus is relatively high, and is only mildly temperature-dependent. This is known as glassy behavior, although it is not unique to amorphous polymers. As the test temperature rises, there is a large transition in stiffness that occurs over a narrow temperature range. The midpoint in this
range is called the glass transition temperature, $T_g$. (The actual temperature at which it occurs is a characteristic of a particular material.) The magnitude of the $T_g$ modulus transition is strongly
dependent on the structure. For amorphous materials the change is very large, and **the stiffness rapidly declines to the point of melting (at which the elastic stiffness is zero)**.*" [emphasis added]

"Stiffness" and even "elastic stiffness" is vague; which stiffness is Hertzberg referring to?

There are [three relevant elastic moduli here](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/overrating_youngs_modulus.htm): [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus), the [shear modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus), and [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus).

A material with a low **shear modulus** is one that rearranges easily—it doesn't really resist changes in shape. Uncrosslinked elastomers at sufficiently high temperatures (not even necessarily above room temperature) exhibit this behavior because the kinked and coiled chains easily slide past each other:

[image]

(Related: liquids, which in the ideal case have a Poisson ratio of exactly $\frac{1}{2}$, can also rearrange easily because they're not very securely bonded in any direction.)

In contrast, a material with a low **bulk modulus** is one that can expand and contract easily—it doesn't resist changes in size. The exemplary material here is the gas; the molecules in condensed matter are butted up against each other too much to permit easy compression. In particular, equitriaxial compressive stress—also known as pressure—pushes the polymer backbone atoms against each other and encounters strong resistance. Thus, the material is essentially incompressible relative to [deviatoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor) (nonequitriaxial) stresses that would cause shape changes.

(A nuance: With increasing temperature, the bulk modulus also drops, but far less than the shear and Young moduli. This point is discussed in Mott et al.'s "[The bulk modulus and Poisson’s ratio
of "incompressible" materials](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022460X08000771).)

As [Roylance notes](https://web.mit.edu/course/3/3.11/www/modules/visco.pdf),

*"As the temperature is increased through $T_g$, **the
stiffness drops dramatically**, by perhaps two orders of magnitude, to a value called the 'rubbery modulus' $E_r$. In elastomers that have been permanently crosslinked by sulphur vulcanization or other means, the value of $E_r$ is determined primarily by the crosslink density... If the material is not crosslinked, the stiffness exhibits a short plateau due to the ability of molecular entanglements to act as network junctions; at still higher temperatures the entanglements slip and **the material becomes a viscous liquid**.*" [emphasis added]

So in general, we can say that a very low shear modulus relative to the bulk modulus implies a Poisson ratio of approximately $\frac{1}{2}$ (from [the relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) $\nu=\frac{3K-2G}{2(3K+G)}$), necessitating easy rearrangement and susceptibility to extension, and minimally chemically crosslinked polymers exhibit this quality if the remaining weak crosslinking interactions are melted away—that is, their strength is easily overcome by the available thermal energy—at a sufficiently high temperature.